# Active record: group results with included associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these associations

```
class Application (id, priority, registration_id, uni_id)
  belongs_to :registration
  belongs_to :uni
end


class Uni (id, name)
   has_many :applications
end

class Registration (id, fname, lname, total_points)
  has_many :applications, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :unis, :through => :applications
end
```

Now I run query like

```
@registration = Registration.includes(:applications, :unis).where('applications.priority = ?', true).references(:applications).order(total_points: :desc)
```

So far it works okay. This outputs the registrations which have

```
1. application priority true and 
2. order the registrations by total_points.
```

Now I want to get the registrations which have

```
1. application priority true 
2. order the registrations by total_points
3. group the registrations by uni id.
```

For example, registrations for uni id 1, should be in one group and should be ordered by total_points, similarly registrations for uni id 2 should be  in second group and should be ordered by total_points and so on. I tried to do something like this below

```
@registration = Registration.includes(:applications, :unis).where('applications.priority = ?', true).references(:applications).group('unis.id').order(total_points: :desc)
```

But this doesn't give me what I want. How should I change my query to get my expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is, say, a Hash of uni_id keys and applications in the values, I don't think you can do this using ActiveRecord but you can do it with native Ruby using the `group_by` method on `Array`:

```
@registration = Registration.includes(:applications, :unis).where('applications.priority = ?', true).references(:applications).order(total_points: :desc).to_a.group_by('unis.id')
```

However be careful with this, since you're pulling all matching records into memory. This can quickly blow up in to a huge data structure, so whatever computations you can delegate to the db you should consider doing so.

---

For the record, you might also want to consider defining a scope:

```
class Application (id, priority, registration_id, uni_id)
  belongs_to :registration
  belongs_to :uni

  scope :priority, ->{ where priority: true}
end

Registration.joins(:application).merge(Application.priority)
```

or a scoped association:

```
class Registration (id, fname, lname, total_points)
  has_many :applications, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :unis, :through => :applications

  has_many :priority_applications, ->{ where priority: true }
end

Registration.includes(:priority_applications)
```